# regex quantifiers in bash --simple vs extended matching {n} times

Tags: regex, bash, filenames, quantifiers

I'm using the bash shell and trying to list files in a directory whose names match regex patterns. Some of these patterns work, while others don't. For example, the * wildcard is fine:

```
$ls FILE_*
FILE_123.txt    FILE_2345.txt   FILE_789.txt
```

And the range pattern captures the first two of these with the following:

```
$ls FILE_[1-3]*.txt
FILE_123.txt    FILE_2345.txt
```

As expected. Great. But now I want to count digits:

```
$ls FILE_[0-9]{3}.txt 
ls: FILE_[0-9]{3}.txt: No such file or directory
```

Shouldn't this give me the filenames with three numeric digits following `"FILE_"` (i.e. `FILE_123.txt` and `FILE_789.txt`, but not `FILE_2345.txt`) Can someone tell me how I should be using the {n} quantifier (i.e. "match this pattern *n* times)?

Comment: Btw.: [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) != [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: Using shell [glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), you'd have to write `FILE_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` uses with `glob pattern`, you can not use `{3}`. You have to use `FILE_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt`. Or, you could the following command.

```
ls | grep -E "FILE_[0-9]{3}.txt"
```

**Edit:**

Or, you also use `find` command.

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/FILE_[0-9]{3}\.txt'
```

The `.*/` prefix is needed to match a complete path. On Mac OS X :

```
find -E . -regex ".*/FILE_[0-9]{3}\.txt"
```

Comment: If it may be useful in this case or for anybody else that comes across this question in the future, `find -regextype gnu-awk -regex ./FILE_[0-9]{3}.txt` also achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Bash [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) does not use regular expressions. It uses glob [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), which is distinctly different, and what you're trying with `FILE_[0-9]{3}.txt` does [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) followed by filename expansion. Even `bash`'s [extended globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob?highlight=%28extglob%29#extglob) feature doesn't have an equivalent to regular expression's `{N}`, so as already mentioned you have to use `FILE_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt`